# Google Calendar API not found - Calendar classes missing

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to make an application that uses Google's API for their calendar service. I am referencing this guide and am now stuck on a step. Specifically, [**this step**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/setup).

It tells me to import these classes:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.*;
```

Now, I have downloaded the (what I thought was complete) library at: [**this source**](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Download_the_Zipped_Jars). But it still gives me an error on the following two lines:

```
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.*;
```

Where can I get those two classes? Or should I follow another example? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use google calendar api you need two particular libs here they are:

- Calendar service java: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/calendar/v3/java
- Google api client java: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-java-client-1.15.0-rc.zip&can=2&q=

And be sure you import all the required jars.
That's all.

Comment: I have added both of those libraries to my project but `com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar` is still not found. Maybe I don't need that? Maybe I should follow another example...

Comment: That's quite strange cause com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar is google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev48-1.15.0-rc.jar (the first link). Are you sure that you correctly set your build path? Did you give the jar lib and not the .zip file ? It's a mistake that always happens to me when I want to do things to fast... (I'm also working on google calendar integration in java this week, and it works fine with those libs). Maybe your problem comes from elsewhere. Is it really the package class that he doesn't find?

Comment: OHHHH, my problem was that I was just importing the "libs" jars, but not the file you mentioned. Because that file is in the "calendar" folder, not the "calendar->libs" folder. Stupid mistakes like that always get me. Thanks a bunch. Maybe just edit the answer saying to check all the folders and include all the jars found everywhere, just in case someone else makes this silly mistake!

Comment: Strange that they didn't include it in the API. Here is a link to a maven repo: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-calendar

Comment: How do you "import all the required jars"? Drag and drop somewhere? Is there an import option in Android Studio? Which jars are required?